# How do I use the address of a changing name of variable

Tags: assembly, reflection, symbols, x86-16

I would like to do something like this:

```
mov al, offset [bx]
```

while `bx` contains an address of a name of another variable. Is there a way to do so in assembly 8086?

Comment: There's lots of example code out there, small & short sample programs that use global variables, for example, so find some and study.

Comment: If you want to look up names to addresses at run-time, you probably want a hash table or other dictionary data structure you can search / query with a string to get an address.  You *can* do that manually, but the toolchain won't help you because there isn't "reflection" in assembly.  Other than maybe opening the executable and reading the symbol table like a debugger would, if it hasn't been stripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no variable names anymore at runtime, that is after assembling. You need to put the *address* of an variable into `bx`, not the name. If the address of an variable is in `bx`, then the instruction you wrote needs to be written without the `offset` keyword and load the contents of that variable pointed to by `bx` into `al`.

Comment: Just to give an example, if we had the variables `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in our program's data segment, we can make an array of pointers like so: `myArray dw foo,bar,baz` and then do `mov bx, offset myArray` `mov ax, [bx+4]` to get the address of `baz` into `ax`, then do `mov bx,ax`  `mov ax, [bx]` to get the value stored at `baz`.